# How to know which of the access points is the root access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I my office I have 3 [Cisco Aironet 1130AG](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/1130/quick/guide/ap1130qs.html) series access points. I want to setup a new access point as a repeater. So far I have configured it a repeater using [Cisco's website](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/12-2_15_JA/configuration/guide/i12215sc/s15rep.html). Also, I am configuring from Windows 7 OS using CLI.
But it is not working, the LED's on the repeater are not blinking at all as it must after the repeater connects to the root access point.

Now I don't know which of these 3 access points is the root access point. How can I know that without pyhsically accessing the devices or do I have to bring a ladder and some cables? :)

I was just wondering if the repeater device is properly associated with the root access point. For that I think I have to view the association list in the root access point. This list shows all the clients as well as the repeaters that are currently connected to the an access point. Can I access this information without pyhsically connecting to an access point? I think no.

There is just one thing that I thnk can be useful is, that when I execute the following command `netsh wlan show interfaces` from the CMD, from any of the machine connected to the wifi then the BSSID and all the other information is exactly the same. *So, I think this is the information of the root access point or am I misunderstanding it?*

PS: Unfortunately I have no information regarding who setup this wifi network and how?
I am not even sure that out of these 3 access points it could be that one of them is the root and other are repeaters, there could be a possibility that all of them are individual access points.

**Update**: Today I finally fetched a ladder. Then I connect to the console port of each of the access points to see how they are configured. I was able to login to one of the access point and it was configured as a root access point. Unfortunately the other access points were password protected any I am unfortunate that no ones knows the passwords. :(
What I did then is I manually turned off the root access point to see if others were repeaters. If others were repeaters then they won't provide internet access to any client as the root access point is turned off. In reality the others access points were providing the internet access, so **Does it means that all of them are root access points?**
So, finally what information I gathered today is that one of the access point is root. Sill wondering about the other two.

Comment: An access point root is any that are connected to the network using a wired connection (Ethernet). So if all three are wired then all three are roots. If only one is wired then that one is a root and the other two are repeaters.

Comment: Yes, but in this case all access points are connected to an ethernet cable as they are being powered over ethernet cable.

Comment: You might consider resetting all the devices to factory default, reconfiguring the entire setup, DOCUMENTING IT, and forgetting about understanding the original config since it appears to make no sense anyway.

Comment: That will be my last option. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out, just wanted to close this question. All the access points were root access points. I finally made chan ges to on one of the root access points and then created a repeater that connected to it. Also, some configuration was done on the main switch for trunk port and vlans, and then only the repeater was working.